# Uploading tables to server in string form?

Tags: python, sql, database

Long story short, someone at my job asked me convert an entire DataFrame into a single string. Never got a reason as to why I'm supposed to do that. I'd appreciate it if someone could give me an explanation as to why this is necessary.

I usually upload tables to a database using something like this:

```
for variable in variables:
    for row in datafile[variable]:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({variable}) VALUES (?)", datafile[variable][row])

connection.commit()
print("Table committed")
```

But now I'm being asked to convert tables into something like this:

```
|00    |01    |       955|      1000|Good |
|01    |02    |       800|       954|Good |
|02    |03    |       693|       799|Good |
|03    |04    |       642|       692|Fair |
|04    |05    |       570|       641|Fair |
|06    |07    |       412|       499|Poor |
|07    |08    |       331|       411|Poor |
|08    |09    |       210|       330|Poor |
|09    |10    |       158|       209|Risky|
|10    |11    |        82|       157|Risky|
|11    |12    |        00|        81|Risky|
```

Where string variables are left aligned while numerical variables are right aligned. The entire thing is a single string. My question is, why is this even necessary in the first place when the first method works just fine? The above string aside from the last column was made using the following piece of code:

```
min_cut = [955, 800, 693, 642, 570, 500, 412, 331, 210, 158, 82, 0]
max_cut = [1000, 954, 799, 692, 641, 569, 499, 411, 330, 209, 157, 81]

empty_str = ""     
counter   = 0
for (min_value, max_value) in zip(min_cut, max_cut):         
    empty_str += "|" + f"{counter}".zfill(2).ljust(5) + "|" + f"{counter + 1}".zfill(2).ljust(5) + "|" + str(min_value).rjust(10) + "|" + str(max_value).rjust(10) + "|" + "\n"         
    counter   += 1
```

Comment: Didn't quite get it, you are wondering why building the string above is necessary, or if the can help you populate the table?

Comment: It's both really. I don't quite understand why building the above string is even necessary in the first place, nor do I understand how it'll be uploaded to a database either. 
If I'm not mistaken, wouldn't the first block of code where I upload tables to a database using pyodbc.connect.cursor be sufficient?

Comment: At a first look, the first snippet looks sufficient. As for the string, don't really know if some Python-based API can help you with that. You can always use `pandas`, to convert to `DataFrame` and then add to the database. It might be the case that your database management application, can support importing in such a format, but you right now, the post is somewhat vague for someone to tell you more.